# Rectangular pressure vessel

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structures, pressure-vessel

I'm trying to find a theory reference for stress and deformation analysis of a closed rectangular pressure vessels with constant thickness subjected to pressure loads.
By now, my test case would be with a square basis and a specificed height.
I didn't find something dealing with this kind of application. I was thinking to apply plate's theory but I'm not sure if it will work properly.
Thanks in advance to whoever will reply.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a tubular type, you can do a simple 2D analysis of the section. You may also want to look to the pressure vessel standards, formulae for rectangular vessel are for example in EN 13445-3, chapter 15.

Note that pressure vessels usually have to be designed according to a specific standards and some provisions may be required by law, e.g., the [Pressure Equipment Directive](https://single-market-economy.ec.europa.eu/sectors/pressure-equipment-and-gas-appliances/pressure-equipment-sector/pressure-equipment-directive_en) in Europe.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tomas Letal, much appreciated.